# Is a WCF service a web service?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it correct to call a WCF Service a web service?

I am working on a assigment for school, and I made a RESTful WCF service and in the report I refered to it at times as a web service. Is it correct to refer to a WCF Service as a web service?

Comment: Yes. It is correct, bro!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WCF is a superset of Microsoft 'communication' services that includes web services.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324).

**EDIT** - To answer explicitly, yes in the context you are discussing the two terms are interchangeable. Just remember that WCF can also include other communcation technologies as well as 'web services'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's reasonable to call it a web service. Bear in mind that you can also use WCF to create a client for interacting with messaging queues - which obviously are not web services.

Comment: +1...bindings should certainly be considered. WCF is *communications* - so it is not solely limited to SOAP and HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) ("*a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network*") using WCF it is correct to refer to it as a web service regardless of the technology you've used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can call WCF service as a web service, but WCF is not limited to only Web service. It more than web service. Microsoft has introduced WCF API's(Framework) for building service-oriented applications.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is a framework for creating services.  It can be used to create Web services, but WCF is fairly agnostic about the underlying communication channel.  So WCF can also be used to implement (non-Web) TCP or UDP services, Windows services, and they can even be hosted in-process.

Conversely, Web services can be implemented without WCF.

Ultimately, 'WCF service' by itself just means 'a service that was implemented using the Windows Communication Foundation framework'.